# Alert Dialog Elipsis

Tags: android, dialog, alert

is it possible to show all the text in an alert dialog if the string is too long? When its too long the dialog doesnt display the whole message and instead puts an **elipsis** `...`

my code is:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setMessage("Do you want to play the game again.")
.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    //Do Something for OK
}
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    //Do Something for No                   
}
}
});
alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a ScrollView and add it to the AlertDialog, and then show your text within that. Something like:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
String str = getString(R.string.text); 
final ScrollView s_view = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
final TextView t_view = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
t_view.setText(str);
t_view.setTextSize(14);     
s_view.addView(t_view);
alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
alertDialog.setView(s_view);
```

Here the ScrollVies contains a TextView which has the text from `R.string.test`, and that ScrollView is set as the content view of the dialog.

Comment: thanks. but my method of creating a dialog is like the one on my question (just edited). assuming that the message on my setMessage is too long. how would i be able to show them all?

Comment: Just put whatever your message is in `str`. You can still set the negative and positive buttons normall.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to truncate your string manually.

Here is a link to help you:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/TruncateaStringtothegivenlengthwithnowarningsorerrorraisedifitisbigger.htm

Comment: But I need to display the whole message. Android is actually cutting of my string in my alert dialog and is showing an elipsis instead.

Comment: So you have to put it in your own layout with a scrollview. it should solve your problem.